# Add "Swipe to delete" but not in all cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview, swipe

I want to add in my tableview the possibility to "swipe to delete", but I don't want this for the last cell of the table!

I can check in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` if the indexPath.row is the last one, but what I want is that if the user swipes on the last cell, nothing will appear (while in the others cells appears the text "delete").

I've tried this

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (indexPath.row != ([array count]-1)) {
   return @"delete";
 }
 else {
     NSString *a;
     return a;
  }
}
```

but of course it doesn't works (the app crashes).
I've tried with

```
return @"";
```

but the red button appears (with no text)!

What do you suggest me?
Thanks!

Comment: In your `else`, did you try returning `nil`? Right now you're returning an uninitialized pointer which is probably causing your crash.

Comment: with nil, the app doesn't crash, but the result is the same (appears "delete")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath row] == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]] - 1)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: Close, but missed: the method you're citing has a `void` return type, yet you try to return a value. You probably mean `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 3):

The app crashes since you return an uninitialized pointer. But even then, you're doing it wrong ;-)

You want to implement [tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aeditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath%3a) and return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` for all cells, except for the last. You need to return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` for the last cell to prevent that it can be deleted.